# pictures validation in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Goal:
Make a evaluation of the picture's format, width and height and then saving it in my program.

problem:
Don't know how to use the `HttpPostedFileBase file` and then sending it to `Image newImage = Image.FromFile(xxxx);` without saving the picture in my program.

1. Validation
2. save picture in my "App_Data"

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]  
public ActionResult Add(HttpPostedFileBase file)  
{
    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        Image newImage = Image.FromFile(xxxx);      
    }

    return Index();  
 }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could do this somehow like the following snippet. Notice the `System.Drawing` namespace reference, you will need for the `Image.FromStream()` method.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Add(HttpPostedFileBase httpPostedFileBase)
{
    using (System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(httpPostedFileBase.InputStream, true, true))
    {
        if (image.Width == 100 && image.Height == 100)
        {
            var file = @"D:\test.jpg";
            image.Save(file);
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

HttpPostedFile has a stream property that is the uploaded data. Use that as with the Image.FromStream method to load the image.

I'd suggest you read the help about HttpPostedFile here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/SYSTEM.WEB.HTTPPOSTEDFILE(v=vs.100,d=lightweight).aspx

Simon